# Select PHP + Mysql

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web, phpmyadmin, crud

Galera, sou iniciante na areá de programação web e estou com problema na hora de criar um CRUD, o inserir funcionou OK, porem o próximo passo que é o SELECT não está rodando como deveria e gostaria que vocês me ajudassem a ver qual está sendo meu erro. estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
<?php 
$conect = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
$db = mysqli_select_db($conect, 'Crud');
$query_select = "SELECT altura, cpf, endereco, nascimento, nome, peso  FROM Cliente";                
$select = mysqli_query($conect, $query_select);
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_row($select);
while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_row($select)) {
    echo "<p>".$fetch[0]."</p>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você pega o primeiro valor da query antes e não faz nada, no while ele pega o valor abaixo e o primeiro é "perdido".

```
<?php 
    $conect = mysqli_connect( '127.0.0.1', 'root', '' );
    $db = mysqli_select_db( $conect, 'Crud' );
    $query_select = "SELECT altura, cpf, endereco, nascimento, nome, peso FROM Cliente";
    $select = mysqli_query( $conect, $query_select );
    while( $fetch = mysqli_fetch_row( $select ) )
    {
        echo $fetch[0];
    }
?>
```

É bom verificar se a query foi executada com sucesso antes do processamento `if( $select )`.

Comment: Muito obrigado João, sou muito acostumado com linguagens do tipo java, c# e quando cheguei em php fiquei meio perdido. Mas vc clareou bastante!