# If com variável do select do banco de dados

Tags: php

Bom dia pessoal!

Estou começando e com uma dúvida básica... preciso realizar um if com uma informação do banco de dados. Faço a conexão e o select, em seguida preciso da variável pra utilizar no if.

```
$idusuario  = $_SESSION['idusuario'];
$categorias = "SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE idusuario = '$idusuario'";
$resultado  = mysqli_query($con, $categorias);
```

Aqui, preciso comparar o valor da coluna "confirmado" do banco de dados para o usuário que está logado, algo como:

```
if $confirmado == 0

{

echo "XXXXX";

}
```

Podem me ajudar com essa dúvida?

Obrigado!

Comment: aqui no site está cheio de exemplos, como esses: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209975/57220 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133463/57220

Comment: Esses exemplos estão utilizando while, exemplos assim realmente têm um monte. Mas essa é a única forma? Porque pensei existir uma mais simples!

Comment: É só trocar o while por if. A diferença é que o while percorre todas as linhas e if só vai pegar a primeira (se a query só retorna uma linha, não fará diferença)

Comment: um select sempre retorna uma lista de resultados, é preciso fazer o fetch, mesmo que seja só pra pegar o primeiro resultado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a relação for de 1 pra 1 na tabela categoria, pode se escrever assim:

```
$confirmado = $mysqli->query("SELECT confirmado FROM categorias WHERE idusuario = '$idusuario'")->fetch_object()->confirmado ;
if($confirmado == "<valor desejado>") {
// seu código aqui
}
```

Lembrando que esse exemplo só serve se seu retorno corresponder a 1 resultado somente, caso contrário você deve seguir o exemplo do comentário do nosso colega Ricardo Pontual, e resolver usando while.

[Select Sum em tabela com PHP/Mysql](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209975/57220)

Comment: É isso que preciso e que eu quis dizer, é apenas 1 registro, aquele do usuário que está logado! Obrigado. Vou fazer o teste!